# How to drop rows from numpy array based on values from another numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a vector of `labels` as shown:

```
labels2 = np.array([0,-1,1,2,-1])
```

And I would like to remove rows from `X_train` that correspond to rows in `labels` that have a value of -1.

```
X_train = np.arange(1,16).reshape(5,3)
```

The output should look like this.

```
X_train_trimmed = np.array([[ 1  2  3]
                            [ 7  8  9]
                            [10 11 12]])
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a simple indexing as follows and then reassign the new result:

```
In [54]: X_train = X_train[labels2 != -1]

In [55]: X_train
Out[55]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: That was way simpler than I imagined! Thank you!